# How can I update my record after I made a check statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got an assignment to do in SQL.
I've got this table:

```
BIll (days integer,
      price real,
      numer  integer,
      total real);
```

I had to create a constraint saying that if number > 10 the total gets a -5 .So total =days*price*number -5; else total =days*price*number

The code:

```
ALTER TABLE bill ADD CONSTRAINT p CHECK (
  (number > 10 AND  total = number*price*days - 5)
  OR (number < 10 AND total = number*price*days))
```

What I have to do now( which I found kind of weird) is to make an update to increase to price with 2% and increase the total.

Here is the code :

```
update bill
set price = price *0.02 + price ,total=  number*price*days
```

But it won't work .It says that the constrint above is violated.How can I do this then?

Comment: You need to do drop the constraint and do the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A constraint is a rule that must apply to all rows of the table, all of the time.

If any insert or update causes any row to fail the constraint, the whole insert/update will be rolled back and the constraint violation error raised.

You have a few options of dealing with this problem, which one you pick will depend on what your business requirements are:

1. Drop the constraint
2. Only update the rows where the constraint will not be violated by the update
3. Temporarily drop the constraint, run your update, then re-add the constraint with the NOVALIDATE option

Options 1 or 2 are preferable, depending on your business requirements. Option 3 has some downsides (e.g. old rows that violate the constraint will not be updateable until they are fixed up).

**P.S.** in your update you may or may not be aware that `price` is the original price, not the updated price:

```
update bill
set price = price * 0.02 + price
   ,total = number * price * days
```

For example, if a record was (2,$10,11,$220), after this update, price will be $10*0.02+$10 = $10.20 and total will be 11*$10*2 = $220 (i.e. it won't calculate the total using the new price).

I suspect your update then should be:

```
update bill
set price = price * 0.02 + price
   ,total = (number * (price *0.02 + price) * days)
            - (case when number > 10 then 5 else 0 end)
```

It seems to me that you may be better off using a virtual (generated) column for `total`.

Comment: Yes ,I know ,but I can't drop the constraint because our teacher will be looking .